# Regarding a shloka similar to a shloka in guru gita

Tags: shiva, guru, shloka, reference-request

> गुरुर्ब्रह्म गुरुर्विष्णुर्गुरुर्देवोमहेशवरः ।
> गुरुर्साक्षात् परब्रह्म तस्मै श्री गुरवे नमः​

> gururbrahma gururviṣṇurgururdevomaheśavaraḥ | gurursākṣāt parabrahma tasmai śrī gurave namaḥ​

This is a very famous shloka, and it has a very similar shloka in guru gita. But not exact, is there any original source for this?

Comment: Some books I have say that it is from Viswasara Tantram. The whole text of this Tantram is now lost.

Comment: The following website also states the same (that it is from Viswasara Tantram) -- https://greenmesg.org/stotras/gurudeva/guru_stotram.php

Comment: Ok you can state that as an answer if you want

Comment: But don't have more references than just that website .. so making my answer a Community Wiki.

Comment: The language of this forum is English. you should provide a translation in question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because forum requires use of English

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda how can a shloka not be in sanskrit and be in english?, I am sorry for my negligence .

Comment: @YOu will not know , this seems to be a verse in Sri Guru Gita( 274 slokas by way of Uma Maheswara Samvada in Skanda Puranam, Brahma Samhita, Uttara Khandam.), does the question ask for any other sloka resembling this

Comment: https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/stotra/SriGuruGita.html

Comment: @Rickross could you kindly let me know the uncoded mantra you were referring to in other question on Gandharva...there is this reputation thing here so I can't do anything aside from answer as a comment please don't mind the irrelevance kindly..
Thank you

Answer (score 7):

As per some books that I have, the said Shloka is part of a Guru Stotram. This Stotram is originally from Viswasara Tantram. At present, this text is lost as a whole. Only some portions of it are preserved as quotes in some other texts like Brihat Tantrasara etc.

The [Green Message](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/gurudeva/guru_stotram.php) website also confirms the same.

> Guru Stotram - In sanskrit with meaning
>
> - **from Vishwasara Tantram** (also many slokas are found in Guru Gita)
>
> श्री गुरुस्तोत्रम्: गुरुर्ब्रह्मा गुरुर्विष्णुर्गुरुर्देवो महेश्वरः
> Sri Guru Stotram: Gurur Brahma Gurur Vishnu Gurudevo Maheshwara
>
> गुरुरेव परं ब्रह्म तस्मै श्रीगुरवे नमः ॥१॥ Gurur-Brahmaa
> Gurur-Vissnnur-Gururdevo Maheshvarah |
>  Gurure[-I]va Param Brahma
> Tasmai Shrii-Gurave Namah ||1||
>
> Meaning:
> 1.1: The Guru is Brahma, the Guru is Vishnu, the Guru Deva is Maheswara (Shiva),
> 1.2: The Guru is Verily the Para-Brahman (Supreme Brahman); Salutations to that Guru.